# Using Core Data Entity Class in Application

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have an entity called *Account* and I have given this entity a class name of *Account* instead of the default *NSManagedObject*. I want to be able to specify objects within my main code to be instances of the class type *Account*.

For example, I want to be able to declare a method such as `-(BOOL)loginTo:(Account *)account`.

How am I meant to go about something like this?

Comment: A few things. First, format all code as code (by surrounding it in backticks). Second, Objective-C uses `BOOL`, not `bool`. Third, of course you can't use a class unless there is one in existence; that's why you have to subclass `NSManagedObject` with a new class `Account`; (please not that your entity does not have a class name of `Account`; you use a class named `Account` to interface with your entity).

Comment: If I knew the above, I obviously wouldn't have asked the question. Please excuse my lack of upper case BOOL, I shall correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an actual Account class that is a subclass of NSManagedObject. Cocoa will then associate the class with the entity, so that new entity instances are of the type Account and vice versa.

Make sure you declare all attributes and relationships so you can access them from the Account class. Declare attributes as properties and use the `@dynamic` keyword, so Core Data generates accessor methods for you.

Comment: In fact, if you create your Account entity in Xcode's design layout tool, then you can select the .xcdatamodel file in project window and select 'New File...' Along with the usual file type choices under 'Cocoa Touch Class', you will also get 'Managed Object Class'. Selecting this will get Xcode to do a lot of the boilerplate .h/.m file creation.

Comment: Also try selecting the entity in the model editor and then select Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass... It will create all properties and accessors and such, even for maintaining relationships.